# Wordpress mysql group by | order by

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

```
$post = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `p`.`ID`, MAX(p.post_date) as `datetime`, `p`.`post_date`, `p`.`post_content`, `p`.`post_title`, `p`.`post_status`, `p`.`post_name`, `p`.`comment_count`, `tax`.`term_taxonomy_id`, `tax`.`term_id`, `tax`.`taxonomy`, `tax`.`parent`, `rel`.`object_id`, `rel`.`term_taxonomy_id`, `t`.`term_id`, `t`.`name`, `t`.`slug`

FROM (`$wpdb->posts` AS p)

INNER JOIN `$wpdb->term_relationships` AS rel ON `rel`.`object_id` = `p`.`ID`

INNER JOIN `$wpdb->term_taxonomy` AS tax ON `tax`.`term_taxonomy_id` = `rel`.`term_taxonomy_id`

INNER JOIN `$wpdb->terms` AS t ON `t`.`term_id` = `tax`.`term_id`

WHERE `tax`.`taxonomy` =  'category'
AND `p`.`post_status` = 'publish'
AND `p`.`post_type` =  'post'

GROUP BY tax.parent

ORDER BY datetime DESC
LIMIT 4");
```

I need to find the latest post for each category and then group the results so I only a single latest post for each category.

I use the; `GROUP BY tax.parent` does not work; `ORDER BY datetime DESC`

Comment: Do you know that there are 4 categories?

Comment: you are doing an illegal grouping.

Comment: @bozdoz yes 4 categories and categories in post

Comment: read first paragraph of grouping in manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html

Comment: What if the post is in multiple categories?  It will be the single latest post more than once. Is that alright?

Answer (score 1):

your IDs are incremental. use that.

```
select ...
from 
.....
where id post_in 
(select max(post_id) from table group by category)
```

if you know how many categories there are, you can do it even better using

```
where post id in 
(select post_id from table where category=1 order by time desc limit 1
union
select post_id from table where category=2 order by time desc limit 1
union
select post_id from table where category=3 order by time desc limit 1
union
select post_id from table where category=4 order by time desc limit 1)
```

or you could use parameters which will give you a perfect result but a very slow query

```
select * from
(select 
@rn:=if(@prv=category_id, @rn+1, 1) as rId,
@prv:=category_id as category_id,
timestamp,
other columns
from (select category_id, timestamp, other columns from ... )a
join
(select @prv:=0, @rn:=0)tmp
order by 
category_id , timestamp desc) a
where rid<=1
```

Comment: Thank you but category id uncertain

Comment: then use the first one

Comment: i added another option, but this one will be slower. It will return exactly what you need, just replace the subquery with your ungrouped query and put in your column names.

Answer (score 0):

Try `GROUP BY t.name` instead of tax.parent, and `MAX(p.ID)` instead of `MAX(p.post_date)`.  I don't think you can use MAX on the datetime (could be wrong, but it wasn't working for me), also I think grouping by t.name is what you want (or t.term_id, or slug).

It seems to be giving me the most recent posts for each category, but it might be a coincidence in my case.