# Php mysql order by datetime desc

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, datetime

posts Chart;

```
ID           post_date 
1      2013-10-20:01:00:00
6      2013-09-20:01:00:00
```

term_relationships Chart;

```
object_id    term_taxonomy_id    term_order

1               1                    0
1               2                    0
1               3                    0
6               1                    0
6               1                    0
```

term_taxonomy Chart;

```
term_taxonomy_id     term_id    taxonomy    parent
1                     1         category      0
2                     2         post_tag      0
3                     3         post_tag      0
4                     4         category      1
```

--

```
$post = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `p`.`ID`, MAX(p.post_date) as `datetime`, `p`.`post_date`, `p`.`post_content`, `p`.`post_title`, `p`.`post_status`, `p`.`post_name`, `p`.`comment_count`, `tax`.`term_taxonomy_id`, `tax`.`term_id`, `tax`.`taxonomy`, `tax`.`parent`, `rel`.`object_id`, `rel`.`term_taxonomy_id`

FROM (`$wpdb->posts` AS p)

INNER JOIN `$wpdb->term_relationships` AS rel ON `rel`.`object_id` = `p`.`ID`

INNER JOIN `$wpdb->term_taxonomy` AS tax ON `tax`.`term_taxonomy_id` = `rel`.`term_taxonomy_id`

WHERE `tax`.`taxonomy` =  'category'AND `p`.`post_status` = 'publish' AND `p`.`post_type` =  'post'

GROUP BY tax.parent

ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 4

");
```

tax.parent = top category id
post_date type datatype

ORDER BY datetime DESC = does not sort properly :(

Comment: If there is a problem with your code, please post what the resulting order is and what the order is you expected.

Comment: I also have no clue what the last two lines are supposed to say.

Comment: the result by;
11.10.2013
11.10.2013
20.10.2013 ..

Comment: Please add that to the question itself. It is unreadable in the comment section.

Comment: the problem: order by datetime desc
But;
group by tax.parent = i'm delete improving problem
But; group by tax.parent and order by datatime = they are the problem

Comment: Post what you're doing in WP terms, along with the calls and filters you're doing, as things stand, it's not reasonable to answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wordpress mysql group by | order by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19430727/wordpress-mysql-group-by-order-by)

Comment: @user2888134 I fail to see how this question, and your second question, differs from the first question you asked about this. Either edit this question and your first question if there is a big difference between the questions. If there is no difference, then you should not ask questions multiple times. Edit your first question to improve it's quality. Questions that are clear are more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select l.* 
    from table l
    inner join (
      select 
        m_id, max(timestamp) as latest 
      from table 
      group by m_id
    ) r
      on l.timestamp = r.latest and l.m_id = r.m_id
    order by timestamp desc

print your query and enter on phpmyadmin. we get exactly error . so you know easily what you want change
```

Comment: OP is using WordPress. This likely makes your current answer wrong, irrespective of its potential merits.

Answer (score 0):

Try with table alias :: `OREDER BY p.post_date DESC`